# Facebook Android SDK Feed Dialog closes itself after some seconds

Tags: android, facebook

I have successfully integrated easyfacebookandroidsdk v2.3 (http://www.easyfacebookandroidsdk.com) by logging in the user and saving the access token in shared preferences. However, when i try to open a FBManager.dialog for publishing a feed, it appears for 2/3 seconds and vanishes afterwards and closes the current activity.

Following is the code snippet :

```
Bundle parameters = new Bundle ();
parameters.putString("name", "name");
parameters.putString("caption", "caption");
parameters.putString("description", "description");
fbManager.dialog(FriendsActivity.this, "feed", parameters, null);
```

Note : I have also tried to open the feed dialog using the "official" facebook android sdk. But i am getting the same response on both emulator and device.

Thanks!

Comment: To add more on the above issue, when i pass the parameters like the name, caption and description of the post, it does not show up on the feed dialog displayed.

Comment: I'm having the same issue would be great to get an answer

Comment: 3 years have passed but this question was not answered !! strange !! Hye @azfar did you able to solve that ??